# Flash Player 10

Tags: flash, windows-2000

I'm trying to install flash player 10 on a win 2000 system that doesn't have web access.  Can Flash be installed without it?

Answer (score 5):

I have successfully installed Flash Player 10 without internet access. Just download the [installer](http://fpdownload.adobe.com/get/flashplayer/current/install_flash_player.exe) from Adobe and transfer it to your Windows 2000 system.

Note that the link is a direct download to the Firefox/Safari/Opera plugin. If you need it for a different browser, go [here](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/), click "Different operating system or browser?", choose your OS & browser, click "Agree and Install Now", cancel whatever window might pop up, and download the executable by clicking the "If it does not start, click here to download" link.